# Can't get the same value of a pointer using the value of a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml

The program crash. I'm trying to implement a `Brick ** create_bricks()` function that return a pointer to pointer of Brick (because I want to create an array of Bricks and return the position of the first). I'm pulling my hair out and the last thing I do after several try and fails, erros and research, was to simplify my code and check value of the pointers line by line. When I dereference `the_brick` as `*the_brick` in the draw function game loop it doesn't get the same value as the one that  `new Brick()` assign to `ptr_brick` inside `create_bricks()` function. I'm using SFML, but the problems is about pointers.

**Note**:  If I return a `Brick *` from `create_bricks` with proper modifications it works fine (and draw the brick), but I need to create multiple bricks, no only one.

```
#include "Brick.h"

int main()
{
    ...

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Brick ** ptr_bricks = create_bricks();
        Brick * ptr_brick = *ptr_bricks;
        window.draw(*the_brick);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
Brick ** create_bricks()
{
    Brick * ptr_brick = new Brick();
    ptrBrick->setPosition(150, 20);
    return &ptrBrick;
}
```

```
#include "Brick.h"

Brick::Brick()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Brick constructor";

    setPosition(10, 10);
    setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 20));
    setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    setOutlineThickness(1);
}

Brick::~Brick()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Brick destructor";
    //dtor
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Returning `Brick *` does not prevent you from creating multiple bricks.

Comment: @bipll Yeah but is even more unsafe.

Comment: At least it's not UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `return` statement in the `create_bricks` function:

```
return &ptrBrick;
```

Here you return a pointer to the *local* variable `ptrBrick`. The life-time of this variable will end when the function ends, and any pointer you have to it will become invalid as soon as the function ends.

The natural C++ solution to return an "array" from a function is to return a `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<Brick*> create_bricks()
{
    Brick* brick = new Brick;
    brick->setPosition(150, 20);
    return { brick };
}
```

If `Brick` is not a polymorphic class you don't even need to use a vector of pointer, but a vector of plain `Brick` objects (`std::vector<Brick>`).

If you persist in using pointers you must allocate an array of pointers to `Brick`, which means `new Brick*[number_of_bricks]` (or `new Brick[number_of_bricks]` if polymorphism isn't needed).

Comment: Returning a std::vector<Brick *> works like a charm. The last solution that you gave me (allocate an array) is the one that  would lead me to the result I was waiting for. Safer the first.